# Enforce pull requests for merges to main, but only on certain files?

Tags: github

Suppose we have a large GitHub repo with many contributors. Is it possible to force contributions via PR for all files in the repo *except* for a few files which can be immediately pushed to main by the contributor?

Use case: suppose 95% of the PRs to the repo are for changes to README.md or CHANGELOG; things you know will not cause any impact on customers if there's a bug or problem, then it may make sense to allow these PRs to be merged without inspection or manual work from a maintainer (or possibly even without raising a PR which triggers notifications to 'watchers'). Can this be achieved?